# Trying to set up Apache+svn, but having troubles. http://localhost doesn't work

Tags: svn, ubuntu, apache2

I'm running Ubuntu 8.10 and I've installed the necessary packages as fast as I can tell. Under System > Administration > Services I see "Webserver (Apache2)" on the list.

Googling around suggested that there might be a problem with the /etc/hosts file not having a line reading "127.0.0.1 localhost", but I checked the file and it's there. I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

To be more clear, attempting to go to http://localhost/ doesn't load any page. The browser just keeps loading, but the page never comes up.

Here is my access.log:

```
192.168.1.101 - - [09/Feb/2009:09:59:54 -0800] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
192.168.1.101 - - [10/Feb/2009:02:10:26 -0800] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
```

and error.log (mostly just me resetting in an attempt to get it to work by fiddling with it)

```
[Mon Feb 09 08:17:47 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 09 15:40:27 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 09 15:42:13 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 09 15:58:27 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 09 15:59:57 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 09 16:31:12 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 09 16:32:45 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 09 16:46:26 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 09 16:49:53 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 09 22:54:51 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 09 22:58:19 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 00:02:04 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 00:04:54 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 00:18:24 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 00:18:25 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 00:28:58 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 00:28:59 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 00:32:10 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 00:32:11 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 00:43:45 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 00:43:46 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 00:45:51 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 00:45:52 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 02:21:34 2009] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Tue Feb 10 02:21:34 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 02:24:39 2009] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Tue Feb 10 02:24:40 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 04:00:33 2009] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Tue Feb 10 04:00:33 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 04:29:03 2009] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Tue Feb 10 04:29:03 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 04:31:12 2009] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Tue Feb 10 04:31:12 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 04:39:45 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 04:41:23 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 04:48:42 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 04:48:43 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 10 04:48:45 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 10 04:48:50 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: What doesn't work? WHat error are you getting?

What is in /var/log/apache2/error_log ?

Comment: Can you show us what configuration you are using?

Comment: Would that be /etc/apache2/httpd.conf?

That file only contains one line:
Servername localhost

That doesn't seem right. There ought to be a lot more stuff there it seems

Comment: You error log is fine, it only shows that you have rebooted apache a lot. Do you have other error logs or log files in that same folder?

Comment: @potyl: I don't think there's anyone who can kill and restart apache that fast manually.  Just look at the timestamps!  It seems for some reason the server is dying and respawning in quick succession.

Comment: @David You're right I didn't noticed the timestamps!

Answer (score 2):

In order to have SVN working with apache under Ubuntu you need to:

- install the proper packages
- enable the proper apache modules
- provide a working configuration file for apache
- creating a repository

I've installed SVN through apache under various versions of Ubuntu and Debian, but never with the newest Ubuntu. I hope that my configuration will help you.

**Install the proper packages**

Make sure that you have the following packages installed 'libapache2-svn' and 'subversion'.

**Enable the proper apache modules**

Go to the folder '/etc/apache2/mods-enabled' and verify that the files 'dav_svn.conf' and 'dav_svn.load' are there. If they are missing simply do:

```
sudo a2enmod dav_svn
```

**Provide a working configuration file for apache**

This is where the fun starts. I've decided to use a virtual host for my own repository even if it's not visible to the outside world. Let's assume that you decide to make your repository available under http://svn.localhost/repos/. First add the following entry to '/etc/hosts'

```
127.0.0.1 svn.localhost
```

Then create a configuration file for apache and save it to '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/' :

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName svn.localhost

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/svn-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/svn-access.log combined


    <Location /repos>

        # Enable the repository
        DAV svn

        # Path to your repository
        SVNPath /home/subversion

        # The following allows for basic http authentication.
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

        # Allow anonymous read, but make committers authenticate themselves
        <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
            Require valid-user
        </LimitExcept> 

        # Have the network shares autocomit their modifications
        SVNAutoversioning on

        # Needed because Microsoft Web Folders defaults to a timeout of 120, a higher number will work better
        DAVMinTimeout 600

        #
        # Broken WebDAV for Windows XP
        #
        BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[012]" redirect-carefully
        BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
        BrowserMatch "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/5.1.2600" redirect-carefully
        BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
        BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS" redirect-carefully

        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header add MS-Author-Via "DAV"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_encoding.c>
            EncodingEngine on
            NormalizeUsername on
        </IfModule>
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Creating a repository**

Create your repository with:

sudo mkdir -p /home/subversion/
  sudo svnadmin create /home/subversion/
  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/subversion/

If you decide to locate your repository under a different folder make sure to update the apache setting of /home/subversion/ in the configuration file.

Update the your password file /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd with command htpasswd.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I still can't access http://svn.localhost/repos/, even after restarting the server or rebooting the computer.

Comment: Go you the apache log folder /var/log/apache2/ and look at the log files. Post everything that you seem pertinent for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can configure which networks interfaces Apache binds to, which may not include `localhost` by default.

Have you tried connecting on your machine's external hostname, or IP (e.g. `192.168.x.y`)?

Also, trying reading the "Installing Apache" part of [this guide](http://ubuntuexperiment.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/installing-apache-php-mysql/) for Ubuntu 8.10.

Comment: I'm behind a wireless router if that matters. I'm using a static IP f 192.168.1.50. Attempting to go to 192.168.1.50 doesn't load either.

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf file?

Comment: It only contains one line: ServerName localhost. 
That doesn't seem right at all. =-/

Comment: That's actually the guide I was already using. I got stuck after the first step. I entered "sudo apt-get install apache2" into the terminal, then once it was installed I went to http://localhost and got nothing. The guide doesn't say what to do if going there doesn't work.